# Can I upload file more than 2gb size in 32bit browser using HTML5?

Tags: html

Can I upload file more than 2gb size in 32bit browser using HTML5 or not ?

Comment: HTML (either 5 or other) has nothing to do with the data transfer. Unless you specify operating system, web server, browser, etc., the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely that you can upload a file that big via HTTP. Not only is unlikely that you can, it is also a terrible idea because before the server saves the file to disk, it will read the entire content in memory and chances are that something else will happen before it gets to write to disk (it'll run out of memory, for example).

If you want to upload a file like this, use sftp.

Answer (score 0):

always uploading the total file isn't the good idea, so upload large file as multipart and at the same time we need high performance, for that use webworkers to send and get requests from server. I hope this should work.